# Find and replace, every other instance

Tags: html, vb.net, replace

So, I have a string that is generated, which contains a title, then a description.

Example:

```
Item1 Description1 Item2 Description2
```

etc ...

I'm looking to format these nicely, such as:

```
Item1
Description1

Item 2
Description2
```

The carriage return is being replaced by `<br />` for HTML formatting.

I have the following code that replaces each carriage return with the `<br /><br />` tags.

```
'//Replace return key with <br />\\ + Debugger
Dim errString As String = EmailBody.ToString

FrmDebug.Label1.Text = "Original String: "
FrmDebug.TextBox1.Text = errString

' Correct the spelling of "document".   
Dim correctString As String = errString.Replace(ChrW(Keys.Return), "<br />")

FrmDebug.Label2.Text = "Corrected String: "
FrmDebug.TextBox2.Text = correctString
'\\Replace return key with <br />//
```

However, I'd like to know how to make it replace ever even instance of this with 1 `<br />` and every odd instance of this with 2 `<br /><br />` to have this format correctly.

Can someone please help me?

I hope this make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here, for instance you could probably work something out with a regex, but I'd just go the simple route and use a loop. I'm a C# guy, but I'm sure you can understand this well enough to do the equivalent VB:

```
string arg = "Item1\rDescription1\rItem2\rDescription2";
StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
bool isSecond = false;
for(int chIndex = 0; chIndex < arg.Length; chIndex++)
{
    char ch = arg[chIndex];

    if(ch == '\r')
    {
        ret.Append("<br />");

        if (isSecond)
            ret.Append("<br />");

        isSecond = !isSecond;
    }
    else
    {
        ret.Append(ch);
    }
}
```

I noticed your original example didn't include those carriage returns in the "Item1 Description1..." so I added them in based on the rest of your question. Let me know if you meant something different.